# What are some advantages of using the SproutCore framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sproutcore

I was going through the [documentation](http://guides.sproutcore.com/getting_started.html), but the overall idea about the framework was not there. What are some of it's advantages or capabilities over a framework like jQuery?

I'm completely new to this, so can anybody help me by explaining how it works and what the main advantages are?

Comment: Quick note: definitely read the About page that Maxim pointed to; it discusses when and why to use SproutCore, but the general gist is that it is a full-fledged web application framework including layouts, views/components, a data source layer (for talking to say a REST API), in-browser sorting/filtering (kinda like SQL statements), minification/packaging and a host of utilities. jQuery is more geared towards adding widgets/functionality to an existing HTML page, whereas SproutCore is designed to write the entire page. SproutCore actually includes jQuery for some of it's DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it is js MVC framework. Like knockout or angular-JS.
Try another link on their site [about](http://sproutcore.com/about/) ))

Example:

```
SC.View.extend({
childViews: ['regularButton', 'iconButton'],
regularButton: SC.ButtonView.extend({
  layout: { width: 120, height: 24, centerX: -70, centerY: 0 },
  title: 'Push Me'
}),
iconButton: SC.ButtonView.extend({
  icon: 'sc-icon-favorite-16',
  layout: { width: 120, height: 24, centerX: 70, centerY: 0 },
  title: 'Love Me'
})
```

})

[Sample for buttons](http://showcase.sproutcore.com/#ui/SC.ButtonView)

I guess it is something like Kendoo UI but strictly MVC based. And it is not replacement for jQuery... It is some another model to manipulate app based on predefined controls (views).